# Image size on screen resolution css

Tags: css, wordpress, thumbnails, screen-resolution, image-size

On my [Website](http://www.portaalnieuws.nl) there are big images (thumbnails). On my big screen (1920 x 1080) they look good. But on my smaller screen (1280 x 1024) they look bad. Standard size is 856px. If the screen can't handle this I want that the thumbnail will be smaller. Some code:

```
article .wp-post-image {
width: 856px;
height: auto;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 3px;
float: left;
```

}

Comment: As somebody has said; `max-width: 100%;` will do the trick. With that said, I have taken a look at your site and I'd suggest just doing `width: 100%;` across the board. The floated text looks a little rough on smaller screens and looks cleaner if you just keep the image at 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
article .wp-post-image {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 3px;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 856px;
}
```

or

```
 article .wp-post-image {
        float: left;
        height: auto;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-top: 3px;            
        width: inherit;
    }
```

or

```
  article .wp-post-image {
            float: left;
            height: auto;
            margin-left: 0;
            margin-top: 3px;            
            width: 785px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To make image act responsively (i.e. andjusting it's dimensions to the size of container), 
add `max-width: 100%;` article .wp-post-image

Comment: As an SO, please consider adding more detail to your answer.

Comment: Actually that is a short answer to the asked question. This is what OP wanted: " ...I want that the thumbnail will be smaller". My code example will definitely do that he wants. If he would like to learn more he could search for "max-width" property by himself.

Answer (score 0):

This was the anwser:

```
article .wp-post-image {
float: left;
height: auto;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 3px;
max-width: 100%;
width: 856px;
```